# Maximizing sum subject to different indicies

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

Suppose I have a matrix, `A`, of size `n x p` with `n > p`, each element of `0 <= A <= 1`. I would like to find `p` elements in `A`, one in each column, such that the overall sum is maximized and each element is in a different row. Thus, there are `n permute p` different combinations to consider. Is there a name for this problem? I found ones such as the knapsack problem, but the setup is different. Additionally, are they are any efficient algorithms to compute this for say `n=300, p=10`? There are a few special cases to check, such as if the max in each column so happens to be on a different row. Otherwise, am I left to dynamic programming? Thanks!

Comment: This is [maximum matching in a weighted bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#In_weighted_bipartite_graphs). Columns and rows are graph parts and cells are edges.

Comment: @n.m. It seems the Hungarian algorithm works quite well for the dimensions I am facing. Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [maximum matching in a weighted bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#In_weighted_bipartite_graphs), also known as the [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem). Columns and rows are graph parts (resp. agents and tasks) and cells are edges (resp. task assignments).

This is effectively solved by the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) which is polynomial.